# Does Azure AD support SAML requests with RelayState as a form POST variable?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am sending a deep link to the Azure AD authentication and I have a successful SAMLResponse.

If I have the RelayState as from POST variable along with the SAMLRequest the RelayState is return in the HTTP POST action back to the Service Consumer URL.

The problem is that the RelayState is empty or blank.

```
https://mywebsite.com/mvc/sso/saml/login

RelayState: 

SAMLResponse: <Some valid SAML Response>
```

#### SAML Request

```
https://myapps.microsoft.com/signin/<app name>/<app id>
RelayState: https://myfakesite.com/saml/complete?session=<session value>
SAMLRequest: <Some valid SAML Request>
```

Does Azure AD support sending the RealyState as a FORM POST variable?

Comment: Just to note that in an enterprise application using SAML in Azure AD you can specify RelayState albeit a hard-coded value - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications

Comment: The RelayState for the Sp-initiated flow can not be hardcoded because it has the users original session from the mobile application.